# Which function required?

Tags: functions, footer

Which WordPress function allows you to include the `footer.php` file into `index.php` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

into index.php or the template you are using

Then create footer.php and add in something like this:

```
<?php
    /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
    * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
    * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
    */
    wp_footer();
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't all code the function is get_footer();?

Comment: yes... get_footer()

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: Reference [Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header). It seems the default footer.php and header.php as well as some other template files are in wp-includes/theme-compat/

Comment: While this is true, you should never edit any core files ( anything inside `wp-admin` or `wp-include` folder as they will be overwritten whenever WordPress updates and you should always keep WP up-to-date to ensure any vulnerabilities get patched.